# MariaDB: can a SELECT query block other queries?

Tags: mariadb, select, update, locking, insert

If I used a stored procedure having only Select queries in mariadb (NO Update OR Insert). Does this Select locks other queries (Select, Update or Insert) using the same tables?

Comment: SELECT without any locking clause (HIGH_PRIORITY, FOR UPDATE, LOCK IN SHARE MODE) shouldn't lock the table.

Comment: @ErgestBasha It is InnoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What storage engine is used ?

InnoDB

> If I used a stored procedure having only Select queries in mariadb (NO
> Update OR Insert). Does this Select locks other queries (Select,
> Update or Insert) using the same tables?

Simple answer, **No**.

The SELECT query which doesn't affect data changes will not lock the table.

With data change I mean INSERT INTO SELECT which is not your case.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER` and other DDL statements may block anything, including `SELECT`.

Ordinary DML statements never "lock the table" in InnoDB, but may lock rows in such a way as to make you think the table is locked.